# java / NoClassDefFoundError error at runtime only

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, error-handling, runtime-error

I'm having trouble including a JAR file that adds a class that will let my main class send emails.

What I have done...

- Saved the EmailAPI.jar file in my folder, as mentioned in below POM text (and it finds it, because in NetBeans I can explore the class)
- Updated the dependency in my POM file, as follows:

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>EmailAPI</groupId>
      <artifactId>EmailAPI</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>${basedir}\src\lib\EmailAPI.jar</systemPath>
  </dependency>
  ```
- Add the import (NetBeans automatically added this when I used the Email class, so it seems to know where to look...)

  import me.nrubin29.emailapi.Email;
- Call the class, directly using the structure provided

  ```
  //send an email
  new Email()
          .withSMTPServer("smtp.gmail.com")
          .withUsername("xxxxx@gmail.com")
          .withPassword("xxxxxxx")
          .withTo("xxxxx@gmail.com; xxxxx@gmail.com")
          .withSubject("[RP] Server has started")
          .withBody("This is the body!")
          .send();
  ```

I can build fine, it all works out...  but then when I try to run it (as a plugin to Minecraft), I get a NoClassDefFoundError, as shown here:
http://pastebin.com/V33gCLVG

I don't understand what I'm missing here. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

It means that you are missing the jar in your runtime environment. You might need to change the scope of your maven dependency to compile.

Comment: I added comments to response above, can you think of anything that might help?

Answer (score 1):

You use `<scope>system</scope>`. Is it available in the Minecraft enviroment? See [Maven, Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism, Dependency Scope](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope): *"This scope is similar to `provided`  [...] "* and under **provided**: *"indicates you expect [...] a container to provide the dependency at runtime."*

Comment: It's not available; I can see from other questions here also that scope/system is my problem. It seems "compile" scope is what I need. I just am confused with where I should put the actual dependency JAR  then...  :-/

Comment: In your local Maven repository. Default in `${user.home}/.m2/repository` or according to `<localRepository>` at the beginning of your `settings.xml`. Did _you_ build `EmailAPI.jar`? With `mvn install`? With this it would be put there by Maven automagically.

Comment: Ok, tried installing it there with some tips from the web, here is the output... giving it another try  http://pastebin.com/0aqLBDgC

Comment: Successfully compiled! Now need to kick everyone off my server so I can restart and test runtime... crossing fingers...

Comment: Ok I've changed Email class to "compile" scope, and after looking at the class there I found it's using JavaMail... so just in case, I've added both JavaMail and its Activation thing to my pom.  New POM: http://pastebin.com/NrqXcL09 . Same error though! :( I've installed all 3 jars using mvn install, and have added my local repository to my POM.

Comment: <repository>
            <id>my-local-repo</id>
            <url>file://C:/Users/Andrew/.m2/repository</url>
        </repository>

http://www.runic-paradise.com/Capture.JPG  < my project area showing it can find the files I mvn install'd ...   I don't get why runtime still cant find the class :-/

Comment: Maybe [3 ways to solve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in Java, paragraph How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError](http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.at/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html) helps.

Answer (score 1):

EmailAPI requires two JARs in order to run. I think they are activation and mail or something. I can look at the project but I think you might be missing them.

Comment: I've added both mail and activation to my project as dependencies but EmailAPI isn't finding them. Opening up the classpath file in EmailAPI, I found this... http://pastebin.com/taAhmxK1 ... so what does this mean for runtime? Do I need to create /src/lib in my plugins folder and put mail/activation.jar in there?

Comment: I've tried putting this everywhere in relation to my minecraft jar, my plugin jar... same errors. EmailAPI cant find its dependencies.